# Comparing non-identical pandas dataframe with a series object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following `pandas.core.series.Series`:

```
Color
Red      4
Green    7
```

and also the following multiindex dataframe. My goal is to create the `Target` column in the dataframe  by checking if the `Value` column in the dataframe is less than the corresponding color value in the `pandas.core.series.Series` and return 1 if that is the case. For example, in the first row, value in `Value` column within the dataframe is 12 which is more than the corresponding matched index value of 4 in the pandas series object and thus Target returns  0.

```
              Value    Target
Color Animal       
Red   Tiger      12      0
      Tiger      3       1
Green Lion       6       1
      Lion       35      0
```

My following attempt gets a `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.Series([4,7], index=['Red','Green'])
x.index.name = 'Color'

dt = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Red','Red','Green','Green'], 'Animal': ['Tiger','Tiger','Lion','Lion'],  'Value': [12,3,6,35]})
dt.set_index(['Color','Animal'], inplace=True)
dt['Target'] = np.where(dt['Value'] < x ,1 ,0 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `lt` instead of the operator, and specify the axis.

```
dt['Target'] = dt['Value'].lt(x, axis=0).astype(int)
print (dt)
              Value  Target
Color Animal               
Red   Tiger      12       0
      Tiger       3       1
Green Lion        6       1
      Lion       35       0
```

`lt` = "lesser than"

Comment: Thank you for the great solution. What should I use instead of `astype(int)` if I have decimals?

Comment: @gibbz00 Not sure I understand the question. `lt` always returns a boolean mask of T/F values which corresponds to 1 or 0, respectively. If you want to convert them to 1.0 or 0.0, then use `.astype(float)`.